# Multiple users, different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am helping the financa company with the yearsly budget.  Using VBA, I set it up so that each department, depending on a password, has access to a sheet in the workbook.  The other sheets are hidden in a locked book, so they only have access to their sheet.  The problem is that multiple departments need to be able to access this book at once, and it seems that if that is the case, the sheets for both departments are displayed.  Is there some VBA or settings that can handle this?  I would need to keep this in Excel and not user AD.

Comment: Sounds like you're (ab)using Excel as a database, to be honest. I wouldn't do this. Excel is not really designed for this.

Comment: Use Access and create an exe that each person can run queries on the Access dbs.